# Defined class seems undefined on compile time

Tags: c++, class, syntax, header-files

I get the following error(s) when compiling:

```
3>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.10
2>ClCompile:
2>  Main.cpp
2>  CWnd.cpp
2>c:\repo\~\clabel.hpp(11): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CWnd'
2>c:\repo\~\cbutton.hpp(11): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CWnd'
2>c:\repo\~\cmainwnd.hpp(9): error C2504: 'CWnd' : base class undefined
2>  CMainWnd.cpp
2>  CLabel.cpp
2>  CException.cpp
2>  CButton.cpp
2>  Generating Code...
2>
2>Build FAILED.
```

My project looks like this (where each part includes the header file one level above)

```
DefaultHeader.hpp : (windows.h, includes CInterface.hpp, other header files)
-- CInterface.hpp : (includes DefaultHeader.hpp, CWnd.hpp, CLabel.hpp and CButton.hpp)
-- -- CWnd.hpp : (includes CInterface.hpp)
-- -- CLabel.hpp : (includes CInterface.hpp)
-- -- CButton.hpp : (includes CInterface.hpp)
```

Here is the definition of CWnd

```
#ifndef __CWnd_hpp__
#define __CWnd_hpp__

#pragma once

#include "CInterface.hpp"

class CWnd
{
...
};

#endif // __CWnd_hpp__
```

I am unsure why I get this error when trying to access CWnd, as CWnd (and all its members) are clearly defined.

The 3 lines the errors occur (snipped out, for reference):

```
CLabel ( CWnd* wndParent, INT iX, INT iY, INT iWidth, INT iHeight, LPCTSTR lpszCaption );

CButton ( CWnd* wndParent, INT iX, INT iY, INT iWidth, INT iHeight, LPCTSTR lpszCaption );

class CMainWnd : public CWnd
```

Strangest part is Itellisense sees no errors until I compile, then they appear and disappear about 2 seconds later.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Strangest part is Itellisense sees no errors until I compile` Intellisense is probably the last thing I'd rely on to find errors.

Comment: I would advise against using the name `CWnd` as it is the name of an MFC class. Is it possible that one of your files indirectly includes an MFC header?

Comment: Thanks Charles, I'll keep that in mind. Solved it myself though :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the header file CInterface was locking up and not including CWnd.hpp in some files. I fixed this issue by having all files include the highest level include file DefaultHeader.hpp instead if their corresponding include files CLabel.hpp, CButton.hpp, etc.